# Array indexing output without the double brackets

Tags: python

How can I print elements of an array without the double brackets [[]] ?

Let's say I have an array:

```
A = [[1]
     [2]
     [3]
     [4]]
```

and I  want to print the elements separately like this:

```
Output:
1
2
3
4
```

Here's my attempt:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(A[i])
```

```
Output:

[[1]]
[[2]]
[[3]]
[[4]]
```

Comment: `print(A[i][0])`

Comment: why are you initializing a nested list if you just want a flat list? is there a reason behind doing `[[1], [2], ....]` instead of just `[1, 2, ....]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the indexing, as i can see, you have list of lists, and you need first value of each list in a list. So you can loop through it and output the first value:

```py
for i in A:
    print(i[0])
```

Or if you have single values inside lists, you could omit them:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in A:
    print(A)
```